# why is my ATI graphics driver not working?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, proprietary

i just installed ubuntu day ago and im total newb in this system. after installation and ubuntu update i found out in "System Info-"Graphics":

Driver-Unknown,

Expirience-Standard

after that i found "Aditional Drivers" utility in "System Settings" and i found there 2 proprietary drivers:

1. ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)
2. ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver

when i activate first, it shows me error and it wont install. 
when i activate second, installs fine and asks for restart and after i restart graphics are slow and choppy, and youtube vids are slower then when was with no driver. and "System Info-"Graphics" shows next:

Driver-VESA: RS780MN

Expirience-Standard

My Graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 3200
My netbook is Lenovo x100e

*update
i uninstalled ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver and  manually installed driver i downloaded from oficiall ATI site and system's graphics are still choppy.
I can opet ATI Catalyst Control Center, and it detect my graphics card, and everything looks fine but system is still choppy.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the current FGLRX drivers, at the time of writing.

Comment: right, a patch is needed to install it correctly in 12.04. I followed this http://askubuntu.com/a/131027/32413, and then it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the same graphic card in my laptop, but I use the open source driver. It works fine, I am able to run Unity and 3D applications normally.

I'd recommend you to install the open source driver  (`xserver-xorg-video-radeon` [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-radeon] - click on the image to install it).

According to the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man4/radeon.4.html), the package should support Radeon Mobility HD 3200.

Comment: thats it thanx Alexandre, i can't comment on your answer, or mark it as answered because i asked question as unregistered member and registered in meantime so if someone can mark his answer as correct and delete this answer.

Comment: @ubi if my answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left side of my post (it should then turn green). Even though your reputation is low, **you** are the one supposed to choose the right answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to go to this page : http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx
Choose your graphic card. (If you are not quite sure, you can verify by typing `lspci | egrep VGA` in your terminal)

Then follow this instructions : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Manually_installing_Catalyst_12.3